# Collaborative Filtering in Spark's MLLib, required an (int) for UserID?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I've been working with Implicit Collaborative Filtering ALS algorithm in Spark's MLLib.

My data is in the following format (which 1st column is user, 2nd is item, third would be implicit of a purchase):

```
user_10, item_200, 1
```

On issue I have in working with the code, is it's requiring using the Rating class, which required the inputs in the following format:

```
Rating, (int(self.user), int(self.product), float(self.rating))
```

So when I attempt to create the model, I receive an error as I can't convert the string for User and Item to int. Is there another option to avoid using the Ratings class or modify so there isn't an int required?

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating
data = sc.textFile("test.csv")

ratings = data.map(lambda l: l.split(','))\
              .map(lambda l: Rating(l[0], l[1], float(l[2])))

# Build the recommendation model using Alternating Least Squares
rank = 10
numIterations = 10
alpha = 0.01
model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations, alpha)
```

Comment: I don't see any problem, if every user and product are different, then you can create a `dictionary` or a `list` of pairs containing the real `id` and the new distinctive `int` id, for every product and user.

Comment: Something else your two `map` transformations can be replaced by only one

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto - users and items are going to be repeated in the dataset

Comment: @jKraut how did you finally solve this?

Comment: @jKraut is there an in-built method other than to create your own dictionary to map string value to a unique int?

Answer (score 0):

Ratings is requiring an int, so I would just transform users and items into integers. Make some transformation to do it when you create your Ratings and it should work.